# circle with only border in threejs

Tags: three.js

i want to create a **circle** with **only border** with **CircleGeometry**.below is the code i used

```html
const geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry( 5, 32 );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );
const circle = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( circle );
```

i used the code

```html
geometry.vertices.shift();
```

but it was not working in **"three": "^0.132.2",** showing as vertices does not exist. so kindly help me to clear this problem.below is the image am facing the issue [image]

Comment: i need only circle with border

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an option, use `THREE.Path` with `absarc()` and `.getSpacedPoints()` method:

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.132.2";
import {
  OrbitControls
} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.132.2/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x404040);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let controla = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

let g = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(
    new THREE.Path().absarc(0, 0, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2).getSpacedPoints(50)
);
let m = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: "aqua"});
let l = new THREE.Line(g, m);
scene.add(l);


window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);

renderer.setAnimationLoop(_ => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
})

function onResize(event) {
  camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for response bro.i tried that but in

let g = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(
  new THREE.Path().absarc(0, 0, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2).getSpacedPoints(50)
);    shoing error as
 Expected 6 arguments, but got 5.ts(2554)

Comment: @ArjunMNair My example is seems working. I'm not familiar with TS, but if you put some effort and read docs, you'll see that `.absarc`'s 6th argument is a boolean value, that sets arc's sweeping to CW or CCW. By defaule it's `false`, thus CCW :)

Comment: soory bro my mistake yup its working fine....really thanks alooot broooo